# Applescript iTunes dictionary explanations

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

I am wondering what the different color schemes mean in the following:

[image]

What does the blue *C* tag mean? and the purple one?

**Disclaimer:** absolute OSX newbie here... please be gentle ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The blue "C" means "command".  You use these like so:

```
tell application "iTunes" to <command> --search, stop, update, eject, etc
```

The purple C means "class".  These represent different types of data that can be extract from iTunes, and selecting a single class shows what properties it has (the orange E).  Classes (or instances of classes, really) are what's returned to you after you request information, like so:

```
tell application "iTunes"
   set currentSong to the current song
end tell
```

After running this, `currentSong` will contain an instance of the `Song` class, which you can then ask for information, like who its artist is, etc.